# Using descriptors with instance variables to store a human's age

Tags: python, object-oriented

I am studying descriptors. They work with class varibles out of the box, but I want them to operate on instance variables too, so I did this:

```
class NumberDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise ValueError("%s is not a number." % value)
        else:
            setattr(instance, self.name, value)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, self.name)

class Human(object):
    age = NumberDescriptor("_age")

    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age = age

a = Human(12)
print a.age
b = Human("osman")
print b.age
```

Is this the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

That looks reasonable; but you should handle the case of when the descriptor is invoked from the class: `Human.age`.  In that case, `__get__` is invoked with None as an argument to instance.  If you've no better use for it; you can just return the descriptor itself:

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    if instance is None:
        return self
    else:
        return getattr(instance, self.name)
```

Another thing you can do, which is sometimes preferred, is to make the descriptor figure out its own name by inspecting the class it's attached to;  this is a little more complicated, of course, but has the advantage of allowing you to specify the "name" of the descriptor attribute just one time.

```
class NumberDescriptor(object):
    def snoop_name(self, owner):
        for attr in dir(owner):
            if getattr(owner, attr) is self:
                return attr
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        name = self.snoop_name(self, owner)
        return getattr(instance, '_'+name)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        name = self.snoop_name(self, type(instance))
        setattr(instance, '_' + name, int(value))

class Human(object):
    age = NumberDescriptor()
```

Other variations to get a similar effect (without using `dir()`) would be to use a metaclass that knows to look for your descriptor and sets its name there.

Comment: Doesn't this make a lookup for every set and get action. It looks like a little bit waste to me.

Comment: yes, this version is a little inelegant; and meant mainly to give you some ideas about how you might use descriptors.  A more reasonable implementation would probably use a metaclass or a weakref.WeakKeyDict to avoid the extra lookups, but I've decided to leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  I'm studying descriptors too.

Why do you use `setattr()` and `getattr()`?  I'm not clear on why you store `age` inside `instance`.  What benefit does this have over this naive example?

```
class NumberDescriptor(object):
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise ValueError("%s is not a number." % value)
        else:
            self.value = value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

class Human(object):
    age = NumberDescriptor()
    worth = NumberDescriptor()

    def __init__(self,age,worth):
        self.age = age
        self.worth = worth

a = Human(12,5)
print a.age, a.worth
a.age = 13
a.worth = 6
print a.age, a.worth
b = Human("osman", 5.0)
print b.age
```

EDIT: responding to comment

Not sure I have a firm handle on descriptors, but [the example](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-example) in the docs access `value` with `self` rather than invoking `getattr()` and `setattr()`.

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12645321/1698426) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12645321/1698426) do not user `getattr()`, they do not use `self` either.  They access the use the `instance` argument.

My example is slightly simpler.  What are the trade-offs?

Just as in the original question, the `b` instance demonstrates that a `ValueError` is raised.  I added a `worth` attribute simply to demonstrate that there are in fact two distinct instances of `NumberDescriptor`.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review and enjoy your stay!  Your answer looks good except for the part where you construct `b`, as both arguments aren't `int`s, so maybe make the example runnable; you could also add a paragraph explaining directly why this setup is better than storing instance variables on the object itself rather than on the descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example, assume I've used your Human class and Number:

```
a = Human(12,5)
print a.age, a.worth
b = Human(13,5)
print b.age, b.worth

# Check if a attributes has changed:
print a.age, a.worth
```

Then you realize, you've overrided also 'a' instance attributes because you actually overrided class attribute :) 
This is why your way to do it isn't exactly right when you want to have descriptor as instance-related attribute.

When you need to have instance-related attributes which are Descriptors, you should to it in some other way, for example store in your descriptor some kind of Dict where you can identify your instance-related attributes and return then when you need them for specified instance or return some kind of default when you call attributes from class (e.g. Human.attr). It would be a good idea to use weakref.WeakKeyDictionary if you want to hold your whole instances in dict.